# Does a lead stop on one journey path track when reentering onto another track within the same journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Say you have a journey that eventually separates into two or more tracks based on an action that a lead takes (decision split). If the lead starts down track A, but then later (while still on track A) takes an action that triggers them back into the journey and onto track B, will JB stop their progress on track A? All of this, assuming that we are allowing for contact re-entry at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set the entry mode to re-enter anytime, then the Contact will be injected into the journey and will concurrently exist in that same journey. They are not automatically ejected from the journey in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you Eliot - is there a way to create this scenario? Is the solve to continually ask JB to evaluate whether or not someone still meets the initial decision criteria?

Comment: Perhaps. You could create a Goal and set the Contact to be ejected from the Journey when they reach the Goal (as the 'Exit Option'), but this could cause both contacts to be ejected from the Journey, depending on your criteria. If you [connect with me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/eliot) we can discuss your scenario further.